# How to merge multiple if statements with identical conditions for different variables elegantly?

Tags: python

#### A basic problem

Let's say, we have a series of variables `var1, var2, var3, ..., var10` and an identical check: `if var[i] > 0: var[i] += 1` for all ten variables. A naive method to check if these variable satisfy condition is like this:

```py
if var1 > 0: var1 += 1
if var2 > 0: var2 += 1
...
if var10 > 0: var10 += 1
```

A more brief way is `for` loop:

```py
for var in [var1,var2,...,var10]:
    if var > 0:
        var += 1
```

How to simplify these codes in an elegant way?

#### Further, a more complex situation

A more realistic situation is that the assignment statement in `if ...`  is not same, like this: `if var1 > 0: var1 += 1`, `if var2 > 0: var2 += 4`,...,`if var10 > 0: var10 += 1`.

How to simplify the checking codes in this situation?

Comment: For more complex situation: use two lists.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem, the complex situation is not only two identical assignment statement, it can be arbitrary numbers. So adding more lists maybe not a great choice.

Comment: Ironically, you pretty much got it in the pseudocode already `if var[i] > 0: var[i] += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

> we have a series of variables `var1, var2, var3, ..., var10`

Even before reading any further, any time you have a series of variables like this, it is very likely that you'd be better off having a single list of values.  But maybe you're doing something completely unique with each individual value and so it wouldn't make sense logically to group them together?  Let's keep reading...

> and an identical check for all ten variables

Ah.

If these variables all had different names and nominally represented different things, the fact that you're doing the same thing to all of them would also in itself be a suggestion that they should be in some kind of collection (if not a list, then maybe a dict).

Taking *both* of these "this should be a list, not ten variables" red flags and waving them around together, the obvious first part of the answer is: instead of `var1, var2`, etc, just have `var` which is a list of ten ints, e.g.:

```
var = list(range(-5, 5))  # [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now it's very easy to apply the same check to each element:

```
for i, n in enumerate(var):
    if n > 0:
        var[i] = n + 1
```

or:

```
var = [n + 1 if n > 0 else n for n in var]
```

either of which produces a `var` with a value of `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.